# Failed to compile the generated registrar code - MT4109

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

Building a Xamarin.Forms application into iOS, I get the following error

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets (_CompileToNative target) ->

MTOUCH: error MT4109: Failed to compile the generated registrar code. Please file a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com

 6 Warning(s)
 1 Error(s)
```

Time Elapsed 00:00:51.5040280

```
obj/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone8.1-10.1.1/mtouch-cache/registrar.m:6806:74: error: expected a type
            -(BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)p0 shouldReceivePress:(UIPress *)p1;
                                                                                    ^ 
    /obj/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone8.1-10.1.1/mtouch-cache/registrar.m:6848:74: error: expected a type
            -(BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)p0 shouldReceivePress:(UIPress *)p1
                                                                                    ^ 
    obj/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone8.1-10.1.1/mtouch-cache/registrar.m:6851:10: error: no matching function for call to 'native_to_managed_trampoline_37'
                    return native_to_managed_trampoline_37 (self, _cmd, &managed_method, p0, p1, "UIKit.UIGestureRecognizer, Xamarin.iOS", "UIKit.UIPress, Xamarin.iOS", "UIKit.UIGestureRecognizer+_UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, Xamarin.iOS", "ShouldReceivePress");

obj/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone8.1-10.1.1/mtouch-cache/registrar.m:1705:13: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'id' to 'int *' for 5th argument
    static BOOL native_to_managed_trampoline_37 (id self, SEL _cmd, MonoMethod **managed_method_ptr, UIGestureRecognizer * p0, UIPress * p1, const char *r0, const char *r1, const char *r2, const char *r3)
                ^ 
    4 errors generated.
```

Which only happens when trying to deploy to a physical device, on simulator everything works great.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same issue with vs 2017 in Virtual Machine in the Mac. It's came because of the auto updating of Xcode 11.0, Xamarin.ios version of the vs 2017 not compatible with the Xcode 11.0,

First I updated vs 2017--> vs 2019 and visual studio for Mac also updated to latest version, after that the issue was gone

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error today. I had XCode 7.0.1 before, looks like the UIPress class is introduced after iOS 9.2 which doesn't come with XCode 7.0.1. So I just upgraded my XCode, which fixed the problem.